# ¿Por qué "montar un pollo" quiere decir montar un escándalo?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones, coloquialismos

Con frecuencia se oye, en ambiente coloquial:

> Cuando Juan perdió el vuelo, **montó un pollo** monumental en el
>   aeropuerto. Gritó tanto que al final le ofrecieron montarse en el
>   siguiente avión.

Es decir, llamamos **pollo** a un lío o escándalo. Como dice el DRAE:

> **[pollo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Tb3F57l)**
>
> 5. m. coloq. Lío, escándalo. Después de la fiesta se montó el pollo.

Dice Fundéu en [**se montó un poyo** - ¿En esta expresión se escribe poyo o pollo? ¿Y de dónde procede?](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/se-monto-un-poyo-13098/):

> El Diccionario académico recoge las expresiones coloquiales montar el
>   pollo y montar un pollo, con elle, con el sentido de ‘armar un
>   escándalo’. La misma grafía aparece en todos los diccionarios
>   consultados.
>
> No está claro el origen de la expresión. El lingüista Patricio
>   Celdrán, en Hablar bien no cuesta tanto (Temas de Hoy, 2009) indica
>   que originalmente se escribía poyo, en alusión al podio o tribuna
>   portátil al al que se subían los oradores políticos del siglo XIX que
>   hablaban en público en plazas o parques y cuyos discursos acababan con
>   frecuencia en enfrentamientos
>   (http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-montar-un-poyo/),
>   pero no hemos podido comprobarlo documentalmente

Por lo que me pregunto: ¿alguien tiene constancia de si esta versión está confirmada? Y, además, ¿se usa también en otros lugares además de España?

Comment: Jamás la había escuchado. Por Colombia no se usa. Usamos "bollo" que también está el diccionario de la RAE como "4. m. coloq. Lío, alboroto, confusión. Se armó un gran bollo."

Comment: @DGaleano ¡pues aquí en España _bollo_ nunca lo oí! Claramente proviene todo de una misma palabra que en cada país se emparejó con una ya existente.

Comment: @fedorqui ¿podrían ser eufemismos para follón por el parecido con follar?

Comment: @野原無 es parecido pero no veo que sean intercambiables, pues _pollo_ es algo así como un adjetivo demostrativo. Es frecuente usarlo en el ambiente laboral: _Estaba tan tranquilo esta mañana cuando llegó el jefe y me asignó resolver el pollo de las facturas impagadas_. En cambio, _follón_ se usa más genéricamente: _Esto es un follón_.

Comment: La versión que había oído siempre es la que aparece en el blog de Alfred López, que enlaza la Fundéu. No es estrictamente algo malo; simplemente, un alboroto. Pero tampoco tengo más referencias que esas.

Comment: Desconozco la expresión. Por si a alguien le sirve, en Chile se le dice "poyo" a un monolito de cemento. (Una casa de madera se construye sobre un cuadriculado de poyos, el mástil de la bandera se para en un poyo, la banca de la plaza consiste en una tabla sobre dos poyos, etc.)

Comment: La pregunta planteada es "**¿Por qué “montarse un pollo” es algo malo?**", que las respuestas anteriores no responden.
En mi opinión, si "montar un pollo" equivale a "armar un escándalo" como se indica en las otras respuestas, es algo malo porque el escándalo atenta contra la paz, la tranquilidad y el sosiego.

Comment: Creo que se refiere al cacareo de las aves de corral, no al poyo. Montar un pollo, es armar un "gallinero". Saludos a todos.

Comment: Esta acepción de la palabra pollo no se usa en Perú. Aquí se suele decir "chongo". La expresión completa es "armar un chongo".

Answer (score 3):

1) El dicho «montar un pollo» es el equivalente actual del clásico «montar un cacao».

2) En la expresión «montar un cacao», el término «cacao» no hace referencia en absoluto al '*árbol de América, de la familia de las Esterculiáceas, de tronco liso de cinco a ocho metros de altura, hojas alternas, lustrosas...*' ni a sus semillas. Se refiere, en realidad, a una segunda acepción, según la cual «cacao» es '*escándalo de voces, gritos, insultos, etc.*', voz de origen expresivo, onomatopeya de la voz del gallo que huye.

3) ¿Quién forma el escándalo? El pollo. Por simple metonimia del agente por lo producido, en vez de montar un cacao, lo que se monta es un pollo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Lo que echo en falta en la respuesta para que sea del todo completa es por qué se usa _pollo_ y no _cacao_ últimamente.